# importing python module failed

Tags: django, python-3.x, anaconda

I am trying to run the development server by using, django-admin runserver and python -m django runserver, the django-admin runserver works but the python -m django runserver gives the following error

```
>         Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__main__.py",
> line 9, in <module>
>         management.execute_from_command_line()
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 367, in execute_from_command_line
>         utility.execute()
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 359, in execute
>         self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 208, in fetch_command
>         klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 40, in load_command_class
>         module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126,
> in import_module
>         return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
> line 12, in <module>
>         from django.core.servers.basehttp import get_internal_wsgi_application, run
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py",
> line 15, in <module>
>         from wsgiref import simple_server
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line
> 13, in <module>
>         from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py",
> line 1, in <module>
>         from django.http.cookie import SimpleCookie, parse_cookie
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py",
> line 1, in <module>
>         from django.http.cookie import SimpleCookie, parse_cookie
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/cookie.py",
> line 7, in <module>
>         from django.utils.six.moves import http_cookies
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py",
> line 92, in __get__
>         result = self._resolve()
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py",
> line 115, in _resolve
>         return _import_module(self.mod)
>       File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py",
> line 82, in _import_module
>         __import__(name)
>     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.cookies'
```

i am new to django, but i tried the following

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=tutorial.settings

PYTHONPATH=/media/mohit/mohit1/WEEKLY/tutorial
```

but it did not work, help

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Also, have you gone ahead and created a project and an app in that project?  You need to run the above command from the root of your project directory.

Comment: no, i have different settings file to create, so django-admin runserver seems better